# Need help modifying these simple regular expressions to match urls

Tags: php, regex, frameworks, url-routing, router

I'm building a router object in a small MVC framework.  It parses url strings to discover controllers, actions, etc.  It is configurable.

Currently, a user can create routes by passing in strings like the following:

```
$this->connect('/:controller/:action/*');
$this->connect('/:controller', array('action' => 'index'));
$this->connect('/', array('controller' => 'static_pages', 'action' => 'index'));
```

And the router builds the following regular expressions from those:

```
#^(.*)/(.*)/?.*/?$#
#^(.*)/?$#
#^/$#
```

Finally, the router tries to select the correct route based on a url.  The urls for the above routes would look something like this:

```
/cars/get_colors/  # will invoke cars->get_colors();
/cars/             # will invoke cars->index();
/                  # will invoke static_pages->index();
```

#### However

My regular expressions are not correct.  The first (more specific) expression can match the second condition, and the second one can match the first.

If I flip the order to check in reverse, The static pages route works, then the controller index route works, but the controller index rout catches all of the more specific ones!

#### Update

I'm using regular expressions because the user can also connect routes like these:

```
$this->connect('/car/:action/*', array('controller' => 'cars');
$this->connect('/crazy/url/:controller/:action/*');
```

Which will build two regex similar to this:

```
#^car/(.*)/?.*/?$#
#^crazy/url/(.*)/(.*)/?.*?$#
```

Finally, doing the following routing:

```
/car/get_colors/             # will invoke cars->get_colors();
/crazy/url/cars/get_colors/  # will invoke cars->get_colors();
```

Comment: Well for starters, your :controller section will wind up matching multiple sections if a route with more than 3 slashes comes in because of the greedy nature of regular expressions in PHP. You're also allowing for empty sections. You might want to sub `/([^/]+)/` in place of `/(.*)/`.

Comment: Right! That's the kind of advice I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you could make your life easier by using the explode function to split the URL into slugs, and not use regular expressions at all.

However, if you must use regular expressions, change ".*" to "[^/]+"

Remember, the dot matches everything, including slashes. The expression "[^/]" matches everything except slashes.

Also, you need to begin your regex with a slash if your string will begin with a slash.

Finally, you need to use the "+" quantifier instead of the "*" quantifier.

Consider these examples, which correspond to the regexes in your post:

```
#^/[^/]+/[^/]+(/.*)?$#
#^/[^/]+/?$#
#^/$#
#^/car/[^/]+(/.*)?$#
#^/crazy/url/[^/]+/[^/]+(/.*)?$#
```

Comment: I *am* using explode to split the url.  I must use regular expressions.  I've updated the question to explain.

Comment: To explain further, the regex is only used to see if the route matches the url and should be used.  Then there is an exploded url that is mapped to the controller and actions.  So I need to master the regex order/syntax in order to make sure the correct route is selected.

Comment: I edited my post with some additional suggestions that should fix your issues. Regexes have a long learning curve. The PHP docs at http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php should help.

Comment: Thankfully my project doesn't involve much more regular expressions.  Also, thankfully, your guidance led me to a solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have used preg_replace function to do so.

preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string)

preg_replace function performs a regular expression search and replace. This will search subject for matches to pattern and replaces them with replacement.

e.g. http://example.com/my-planet-earth/

I am talking about formatting ‘my-planet-earth’. Here, $string can be ‘My Planet Earth’ and the $urlKey will be ‘my-planet-earth’$string = "planet+*&john doe / / \ \ ^ 44 5 % 6 + - @ ku ! ~ ` this";
$urlKey = preg_replace(array('/[^a-z0-9-]/i', '/[ ]{2,}/', '/[ ]/'), array(' ', ' ', '-'), $string);
// outputs: planet-john-doe-44-5-6---ku-this

Hope this helps.